# Constructing XOR/3 in Prolog

Tags: prolog, xor

I have the following clauses for /3 propositional logic.

```
statement(false).
statement(true).

not(false, true).
not(true,   false).

and(false, false, false).
and(false, true,   false).
and(true,   false, false).
and(true,   true,   true).

or(false, false, false).
or(false, true,   true).
or(true,   false, true).
or(true,   true,   true).

implying(X, Y, Z) :- not(X, Not_X) , or(Not_X, Y, Z).
```

How would I go about adding XOR clauses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
xor(false, false, false).
xor(false, true,  true).
xor(true,  false, true).
xor(true,  true,  false).
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use one of the [equivalences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Equivalences,_elimination,_and_introduction): selecting the first one, (P ∨ Q) ∧ ¬ (P ∧ Q),

```
xor(P,Q,R) :-
    or(P,Q,O),
    and(P,Q,A),
    not(A,N),
    and(O,N,R).
```

you get:

```
?- forall(xor(P,Q,R),writeln(xor(P,Q,R))).
xor(false,false,false)
xor(false,true,true)
xor(true,false,true)
xor(true,true,false)
true.
```